# Google Chrome の AutoPatchWork プラグインがアンインストール出来ない

Tags: google-chrome

ブラウザでこのようなエラーを吐いていました。オートパッチワークというプラグインがエラーの種になっていると思い、オートパッチワークを消しましたが、消えませんでした。。

```
Error in event handler for (unknown): SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '(//article[not(contains(../@class,'widget'))][not(contains(@class,'columns four'))]|//*[starts-with(@id,'post-')][not(contains(@id,'post-rating'))])[not(.//*[contains(@class,'admz')])][not(id('load-more-posts') or @id='fpost' or contains(@class,'carousel') or contains(@class,'slider'))][..[not(self::h2)][not(@id='side')][not(contains(@class,'thumbnail'))][not(following-sibling::*[not(@id='side')][article or *[starts-with(@id,'post-')]])]/*[self::article or starts-with(@id,'post-')]/following-sibling::*[self::article or starts-with(@id,'post-')][not(contains(@id,'nav'))]]|id('content')[count(div)>1]/div[contains(@class,'post')]' is not a valid XPath expression.
    at get_next_elements (chrome-extension://aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd/includes/AutoPatchWork.js:768:19)
    at AutoPatchWork (chrome-extension://aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd/includes/AutoPatchWork.js:154:25)
    at chrome-extension://aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd/includes/AutoPatchWork.js:109:14
    at init (chrome-extension://aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd/includes/AutoPatchWork.js:108:27)
```

Comment: 貼って頂いたログの最後に

> at init (chrome-extension://aeolcjbaammbkgaiagooljfdepnjmkfd/includes/AutoPatchWork.js:108:27)

のようなエラーがあるので、Chromeプラグインのエラーのように見えますが、プラグインは本当に無効にしたんでしょうか？

Comment: wordpress 関係ないので修正しました。起きている問題はサーバ側(wordpress)でなく、くらさわゆうさんのブラウザで起きている問題です。他のPCでは問題が出ていないはずです。